# OpCache Zend understanding flush / restart

Tags: caching, cache-control, opcache

Iam using OpCache Zend I switched from APC. It's have been for me to understand why OPCache flush memory wheen it rise to end level. In logic memory should be filled and OpCache should hold it till 
Oom restart or Hash restarts occur. Right ?

I have about 65 domains (Wordpresses, Joomla, Magento, Pure PHP)

My Server spec are :
Intel Xeon X3440 Quad-Core
Memory 16GB
x2 1500 GB SATA II-HDD 7.200 rpm
CentOS 5 - Plesk 10 - RAID 1

My config for Zend OPcache are :

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=400
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=16
opcache.max_accelerated_files=7963
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=5
opcache.use_cwd=1
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
;opcache.revalidate_path=0
;opcache.save_comments=1
;opcache.load_comments=1
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
;opcache.enable_file_override=0
;opcache.optimization_level=0xffffffff
;opcache.inherited_hack=1
;opcache.dups_fix=0
opcache.blacklist_filename=/etc/php.d/opcache*.blacklist
;opcache.max_file_size=2097152
opcache.consistency_checks=1
opcache.force_restart_timeout=180
;opcache.error_log=
;opcache.log_verbosity_level=1
;opcache.preferred_memory_model=
;opcache.protect_memory=0
```

[image]

At this moment I have 7963 max accelerated files, but i have tryed with more.
Strange is that, if flush occur there is no information about any OPCache restart.

Comment: I'm just wondering is this an old version of Opcache you use? because now we have v7.0.5 out there with many fixes... possibly you have some mis-configurations.

Comment: https://tideways.io/profiler/blog/fine-tune-your-opcache-configuration-to-avoid-caching-suprises